# A reliable source of Cas9?

Tags: genetics, crispr

I live in Egypt, and I do want to perform CRISPR-Cas9 genome modification, but there are no reliable sources of Cas9. I can order some Cas9 online from the US, but not much. So... my question is, is there any way I can replicate a small amount of Cas9 to get a bigger amount? Or maybe extract some from S. Pyogens? I've been searching about this for quite some time, so any support would be really appreciated.

Note: I'm not really the "Biology" guy, so please tell me if I sound ridiculous.

Comment: You could get a synthetic gene for Cas9 and overexpress it heterologously.

Comment: I'm more curious why you are planning to do some genome modification while not being the biology guy...

Comment: I might be wrong but I'd guess it'll probably be more expensive to figure out how to produce the compounds you need than to just buy them (esp. if you're not a "biology guy").

Comment: Well.. I can't exactly tell you what I'm working on because I signed an NDA, but what I can tell you is that I'm a programmer and I want to create bacteria that can pass information through controllable electrical connections(interfaced with a microcontroller).

Comment: @None Hi, would be interesting to discuss more on your project